# Changing Encyption on Sql Server 2016 Column from Triple Des to AES256

Tags: sql-server-2016, encryption

In the process of changing encryption from Triple Des to AES 256.  Have been advised to have keys for both available for clients on server until migration is complete.  First question is can I have a key for both Triple Des and AES 256 on the server at the same time.  Second question is how to unencrypt the data in the column that is already encrypted with Triple Des and re-encrypt with AES 256?  Can it be done in place or does the table need to be dropped and recreated?